# Чем методы отличаются от параметров в запросах

Tags: java, android, retrofit, методы, передача-параметров

При настройке интерфейса в Retrofit я заметил сходство двух терминов: методы и параметры. Я не могу понять в чем меду ними разница и как определить, что чем является, подскажите пожалуйста, если не сложно.

Comment: в общем случае методы это какие то действия, а параметры - значения для этих действий. например метод `getURL(http://site.org)` - getURL это метод, который производит действие, получает информацию с сайта, `http://site.org` - параметр этого метода, который указывает с какого именно сайта получать информацию. если вас интересует конкретная непонятная вам ситуация, то ее нужно привести в вопросе для примера, так как сейчас из вашего вопроса не вполне понятно, что же именно вам не понятно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предположим, вы хотите сварить яйца. Можно создать **метод**: `сварить яйца (toCookEggs)`, который будет описывать действия, необходимые для их варки (взять кастрюлю, положить яйца, залить водой и т.д.).

Метод может не иметь параметров, а может иметь. Пусть вам необходимо сварить *определенное* количество яиц и до *определенной* степени готовности.

Тогда в методе следует прописать **параметры** `количество яиц (amount)` и `желаемое состояние готовности (condition))`.

В итоге метод с такими параметрами может быть объявлен следующим образом:

```
Egg[] toCookEggs(int amount, Condition condition) {
    /*
    - взять кастрюлю;
    - положить amount яиц;
    - залить водой;
    - зажечь конфорку;
    - варить до condition;
    - return вареные яйца 
    (Egg[] в начале объявления как раз и показывает, что должен вернуть метод)
    */
}
```

В нужное время, в нужном месте и с нужными параметрами наш метод может быть вызван, например, так:

```
Egg[] eggsForBreakfast = toCookEggs(2, SOFT_BOILED); // В скобках 
Egg[] eggsForPicnic = toCookEggs(6, HARD_BOILED);    // указываются конкретные 
Egg[] eggsForDinner = toCookEggs(1, MIDLE_BOILED);   // значения параметров
```